# I´m trying to call other activity with MenuItem

Tags: java, android, android-activity, oncreateoptionsmenu

I`m trying to call other activity with onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected, but i dont know is imposible to debug and it doesn´t do the action, i have

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.login_settings, menu);º
    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getGroupId();
    if(id == R.id.contactMenu) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And the MenuItem

```
 <group
        android:id="@+id/contactMenu"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/contactSettings"
                android:icon="@drawable/correo"
                android:title="@string/ContactUs_settings" />
    </group>
```

thank you so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change just like below code and works fine.You must need to use ItemId for select menuItem

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId(); //you must use item id not group id
    if(id == R.id.contactSettings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i tried and nothing, is still not working, thank you for your help!!

Comment: i also removed all groups, there was only items,,, the same,,